# raspberry pi 3 webbrowser controlled by buttons (Python)

Tags: python, chromium, raspberry-pi3, gpio

hi I am trying to get 2 webcam outputs to be displayed in a webbrowser which runs in full screen mode.
So far it works aslong as I keep the fullscreen/kiosk disabled, once the full screen is on, my script pauses.
When I close the webbrowser the script continues and I can use my buttons which open a new browser and then the script pauses again (the purpose is that the script loops endlessly without pauses)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import os
url1 = 'http://10.0.0.31/mjpg/video.mjpg'
url2 = 'http://10.0.0.32/mjpg/video.mjpg'
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
array = [4,17]
GPIO.setup(array, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
os.system('chromium-browser --app=http://10.0.0.31/mjpg/video.mjpg --kiosk')
while True:
if ( GPIO.input(17) == False ):
    print('Button 1 Pressed')
    os.system('date')
    os.system('pkill chromium-browser')
    print (GPIO.input(17))
    os.system('chromium-browser --app=http://10.0.0.32/mjpg/video.mjpg --kiosk')
    sleep(0.5)
if ( GPIO.input(4) == False ):
    print('Button 2 Pressed')
    os.system('date')
    os.system('pkill chromium-browser')
    print (GPIO.input(4))
    os.system('chromium-browser --app=http://10.0.0.31/mjpg/video.mjpg --kiosk')
    sleep(0.5)
else:
    os.system('clear')
    print ('Press a key')
    sleep(0.1)
```

Is there a way to fix this without big changes (as I noticed a lot of people are fan of selenium, that's not an option) and using subprocess instead of os.system gives same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because os.system() waits for a process to finish, and won't continue your code until this happens. By using the "&" at the end of your command, the command does not have to finish, and your buttons should still be useable.

```
#Import libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import os

#Set up the URLs
url1 = 'http://10.0.0.31/mjpg/video.mjpg'
url2 = 'http://10.0.0.32/mjpg/video.mjpg'

#Set up GPIO pins
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
array = [4,17]
GPIO.setup(array, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#Open the first webpage
os.system('chromium-browser --app=http://10.0.0.31/mjpg/video.mjpg --kiosk & ')

while True:
    if ( GPIO.input(17) == False ):
        print('Button 1 Pressed')
        os.system('date')
        os.system('pkill chromium-browser')
        print (GPIO.input(17))
        os.system('chromium-browser --app=http://10.0.0.32/mjpg/video.mjpg --kiosk &')
        sleep(0.5)
    if ( GPIO.input(4) == False ):
        print('Button 2 Pressed')
        os.system('date')
        os.system('pkill chromium-browser')
        print (GPIO.input(4))
        os.system('chromium-browser --app=http://10.0.0.31/mjpg/video.mjpg --kiosk &')
        sleep(0.5)
else:
    os.system('clear')
    print ('Press a key')
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot , easier then this isn't possible, I don't have the rep to upvote yet but this was the solution

Comment: Thanks, if it is possible to do so, please up vote this answer or mark it as the accepted solution. Glad that I was able to help.